# Cloud server for KeePass synchronization

Tags: sync, webserver, dropbox, cloud-storage, keepass

I have a KeePass password Database which I use on several computers. This database relies on a separate XML file to function. It is possible for a server to have both the XML and KDBX in the same directory and KeePass will be able to find the XML.
My question is, what is a free cloud hosting service I can use that can have speed of 100KB/s up and down, and can host a couple of MB's. I can't use DropBox or Google drive because there formatting of folder is wrong. If I want to access the KDBX, I have a specific URL (drive.google.com/Folder/(randomchars) I then have a preview. Getting the file's individual URL is possible, but it can't link back to the folder for the XML. Same with dropbox. I am looking for something that stores the files in www.domain.com/Folder/Database.kdbx and www.domain.com/Folder/Database.xml
I also require some sort of encryption between my computer and the cloud-server.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you not just use a relative path in the XML?

Comment: Any cloud storage provider is going to have speeds that exceed 100KB/sec that is extremely slow.  We don't do service recommendations here at Superuser, and there isn't a Stackexchange website, where this question would be on topic.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am going to setup ownCloud on my raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0):

I have found nothing that can perform these operations. I am going to use the free service ownCloud and my Raspberry Pi to host my own cloud server.